# am trying to click on dropdown and it is working on my local system but when in production am getting webdriver exception

Tags: python, exception, webdriver

I'm trying to click on dropdown and it is working on my local system but when in production am getting webdriver exception error:

```
message: move target out of bounds
```

I tried with different xpath used:

```
csv = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'ComboboxOption__ComboboxOptionText-sc-1oh0c26-2') and text()='CSV']")))
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(csv).click().perform()
here same action to be performed twice so for other i used same approch 
csv = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'ComboboxOption__ComboboxOptionText-sc-1oh0c26-2') and text()='CSV']")))
        actions = ActionChains(driver)
        actions.move_to_element(csv).click().perform()
```

but it is not working